# Change character color with regex in typescript/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

why is my class not being using in my regex function? I am very confused on what is going on.

Regex

```
let headingTitle: Element | null = document.querySelectorAll("h2")
   
  headingTitle.innerHTML =  headingTitle.textContent?.replace(/[Miss]/gi,"<span className='title'>Miss</span>");
```

innerHTML is undefined. it prints the nodelist twice. First with all the h2 tags and then it does it again and says nodelist[innerhtml undefined]. See image:

[image]

I console logged it and saw that className is still an empty string
__reactFiber$f0qledvdhz7: FiberNode {tag: 5, key: null, elementType: 'h2', type: 'h2', stateNode: h2, …}
__reactProps$f0qledvdhz7: {children: 'Miss'}
accessKey: ""

```
childElementCount: 0
childNodes: NodeList [text]
children: HTMLCollection []
classList: DOMTokenList [value: '']
className: ""
```

mapped data

```
<div style={hoverStyle} className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-2 p-2 mt-20">
        {data?.results.filter((val: any)=>{
          if (searchUser === "") {
            return val
          } else if (val.name.first.toLowerCase().includes(searchUser.toLowerCase())) { 
              return val          
          } else if (val.email.toLowerCase().includes(searchUser.toLowerCase())){
            return val
          } else if 
            (val.location.city.toLowerCase().includes(searchUser.toLowerCase())){
              return val
            } 
        }).map((d: any) => (
              
          <div style={hoverStyle} className="text-blue-900 ease-in-out delay-150 hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 duration-300  border-white shadow-slate-500 bg-white hover:opacity-95 rounded-lg container p-5">
            <img className="rounded-full w-44 h-44 " src={d.picture.large} />
            <h2>{d.name.title}</h2>
            <h3 className="font-bold text-3xl font-serif">
```

Answer (score 0):

It already feels very wrong using `document.querySelectorAll()` in ReactJs. You should consider doing it with a React way.

However, `document.querySelectorAll()` returns an array of objects and you are trying to access it incorrectly.

Use just `querySelector` or access the first element of it. If the goal is to do the operation to all of the returned elements then it has to be iterated either with for loop, .forEach, or any other possibilities.

In vanilla javascript, you'd do like this below

```js
const h2s = document.querySelectorAll("h2");
const replaceStr = "<span class='title'>Miss</span>";
// It has to be innerHTML if you want to be html rendered. 
// TextContent would dsplay html as a text
h2s.forEach((h2) => {
  h2.innerHTML = h2.innerText.replace(/miss/ig, replaceStr)
});
```

```css
.title{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h2>Some text</h2>
<h2>miss</h2>
<h2>Another Miss</h2>
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks for leaving an answer.

Comment: didn't work, i tried something like yours before and had the same problem. I think it's specific to typescript and how im fetching the data from an api.